# A structure of the group of automorphisms of an infinite binary tree

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-groups, trees

My friend asked me to ask his question here. Where he can find (a paper or a book) *containing a complete description (with the proof) of a structure of the group of automorphisms of an infinite binary tree*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming you mean a binary rooted tree. I don't know your definition of complete.  The group is the infinite permutational wreath product of symmetric groups of degree 2.  Good references are [Automata, dynamical systems and infinite groups](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~grigorch/publications/PSIM128.PS) by R. Grigorchuk, V.V.Nekrashevich, V.I.Sushchanskii, Proc. Steklov Inst. Math. v.231 (2000), 134-214 and Cyclic renormalization and automorphism groups of rooted trees by Bass, Otero-Espinar, and Rockmore.

Comment: One more thing: The (almost) full automorphism group $Aut_+(T)$ is an HNN extension of $Aut(T,r)$ (the group described in your answer), where $r$ is a fixed vertex of $T$ (a "root"). Here $Aut_+(T)$ is the subgroup of $Aut(T)$ of index 2 consisting of automorphisms acting without inversions. The edge subgroup here is also well-understood, it is isomorphic to the direct product $Aut(T,r)\times Aut(T,r)$.

Comment: @Misha, If the OP means by binary tree the Cayley graph of the free monoid on 2-generators, then the root is the only degree 2 vertex and so must be fixed.

Comment: I see, I was thinking about the regular trivalent tree.

Comment: The op was not clear on this point.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks a lot. My friend said that you are a well-known specialist in this area and he is happy with your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Topics in geometric group Theory by P. de la Harpe should also contain this and is very well written.

Comment: This is also a good one.